# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor python 3.7 CSV writer

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to write data into csv file. I am using python 3.7 64-bit pycharm in Windows 10.

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

**Getting that error**

C:\Users\Ehtisham\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Ehtisham/Documents/Python/OLX/test.py
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ehtisham/Documents/Python/OLX/test.py", line 6, in 
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])

**OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor**

Comment: Could the file already be open in another application, or elsewhere in your program?

Comment: File is not open in any other program

Comment: when i am reading file getting output properly

Answer (score 1):

I have change my project loaction its works smoothly. In Window 10 creating problem by Windows Defender.

Comment: The problem was the Windows Defender for me ‍♂️ Thanks